# How do I invoke a helper module method from a Rails service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, module, helper

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have created app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb

```
require "resolv-replace.rb"
require 'open-uri'

module WebpageHelper

  def self.max_attempts
    3
  end

  def get_url(url)
    attempts = 0
    begin
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    rescue => e
      puts "error: #{e.message}"
      attempts = attempts + 1
      if attempts <= max_attempts
        retry
      end
    end
  end

end
```

How do I invoke this helper method from another Rails service (NOT a controller)?  I’ve tried

```
doc = WebpageHelper::get_url(url)
```

But that results in an error “undefined method `get_url' for WebpageHelper:Module”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. either include WebpageHelper and then just use `get_url` method or define `get_url` as a module function.

```
module WebpageHelper

  ...

  module_function :get_url
end

and then you can use this like
WebpageHelper.get_url
```